# JS delaying page load even though it's in document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that I want to have appear on my page after the user has been there for a few seconds. To achieve this, I used a sleep function and put it inside $(document).ready().  The idea is that the page will load and then the sleep will start.  However what I'm seeing is that the sleep function is actually delaying the page load. Any idea what's wrong?

```
function sleep(miliseconds) {
       var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

       while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
       }
   }


$(document).ready(function(){   
    if ( $( ".email_tab" ).length ) {
        sleep(8000);
$(".email_tab").toggleClass("email_tab_hide").toggleClass("email_tab_appear");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sleep function consumes your browser cpus and freezes it.

What you want is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    if ( $( ".email_tab" ).length ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".email_tab").toggleClass("email_tab_hide").toggleClass("email_tab_appear");
        }, 8000);
    }
});
```

Your problem may be that when the document is ready, and email_tab length is zero, the setTimeout won't run.

Answer (score 0):

In JS you should use [setTimeout();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) instead custom `sleep()` function

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $(".email_tab").toggleClass("email_tab_hide").toggleClass("email_tab_appear");
}, 8000)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$(document).ready` callback actually runs before the page is fully loaded. It just ensures that the whole DOM is available for manipulating. Your `sleep` busy-loop then delays the rest of the loading process. You should use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) instead.